# I want Lay on Hands, but I think Paladins are campaign-wreckers and won't play one. What are my options?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature

I've DM'd for Paladins as PCs before, and my experience is that they can unwittingly derail a campaign, even without any effort or powergaming on the part of the player. As such, now that I'm a player, I refuse to play a Paladin. I don't want to inflict campaign-derailing sidequests just because I accidentally broke the Code and have to go on a redemption quest just to be a useful party member; I don't want to torment my DM with at-will *detect evil*, like I have been tormented.

I still like the character concept and some of the abilities though; I especially like their **Lay on Hands** class feature. So, as a first stab at finding acceptable alternatives to the Paladin class, I was wondering if there were abilities one could acquire that work *just like* or *very close to* Lay on Hands, but without being a Paladin.

Comment: Related: [How do I play a paladin without being a stick in the mud?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18947/how-do-i-play-a-paladin-without-being-a-stick-in-the-mud)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A quick list of non-paladin ways to get *Lay on Hands*:

- *Hospitaler* prestige class (*Complete Divine* p48) - level 1
- *Champion of Corellon Larethian* prestige class (*Races of the Wild* p113) - level 1, named "Corellon's blessing"
- *Knight of the Pearl* prestige class (*Stormwrack* p52) - level 1

Of these, only Champion is somewhat useful.

Depending on what exactly do you require of "similar" ability, you may also want to take a look at

- *Touch of Vitality*, class feature of *Dragon Shaman* (*Player's Handbook 2*, p14)
- ex-cleric *Defiant*, prestige class (*Planar Handbook* p44), 1 level of cleric traded
- *Sentinel of Bharrai* prestige class (*Book of Exalted Deeds* p69), 7th level

Of these, *Touch of Vitality* and *Sentinel of Bharrai* are usable - the latter being a full-caster prestige class and the former being a class feature of a half-decent class.

There may be more.